# Why my code takes me to different URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

First of all, My resource is nested using **to_param** for slug at Community model.

I'm at example.com/shop/walmart/topic/14/edit .
If I press update without captcha input, it obviously should take me back to edit page again with flash error message.
However it takes me to  example.com/shop/14/topic/14/edit .  <= it's taking the same parameter. it should take 'walmart' which is **community_name** for first argument, and **:id** for topic.
All the fields are set the same with what I typed in at the previous page. 
How can I avoid this? it should redirect to the same url as previous page.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities, :path => "shops", do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topics"      
end
```

**controller**

```
def simple_captcha_check
    if !simple_captcha_valid?
        flash[:error] = 'Wrong Captcha!'

        if request.put? # We came from an edit request
          @community_topic = CommunityTopic.find(params[:id])
          @community_topic.attributes = params[:community_topic]
          render :action => :edit
        elsif request.post? # We came from a new request
          @community_topic = CommunityTopic.new params[:community_topic]
          render :action => :new
        end

    end
end
```

**models/community.rb** Note that I use slug here

```
def to_param
  "#{community_name}"
end
```

**views/community_topics/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @community_topic, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
  <%= show_simple_captcha(:label => "human authentication") %>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                community_topic_index_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**rake routes | grep community_topic**

```
      community_community_topics GET    /shops/:community_id/topics(.:format)          community_topics#index
                                 POST   /shops/:community_id/topics(.:format)          community_topics#create
   new_community_community_topic GET    /shops/:community_id/topics/new(.:format)      community_topics#new
  edit_community_community_topic GET    /shops/:community_id/topics/:id/edit(.:format) community_topics#edit
       community_community_topic GET    /shops/:community_id/topics/:id(.:format)      community_topics#show
                                 PUT    /shops/:community_id/topics/:id(.:format)      community_topics#update
                                 DELETE /shops/:community_id/topics/:id(.:format)      community_topics#destroy
```

By the way, my index action in controller is just like this, and it's working fine!

**community_topics_controller.rb #index**

```
  def index
    @community = Community.find_by_community_name(params[:community_id])
    @community_topics = @community.community_topics

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @community_topics }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your controller actions, and don't know names of variables, but anyway in case of nested routes you have to define all urls precisely with named routes, or with polymorphic helper (as i do).

So your form helper must be looking as next:

```
<%= form_for([@community, @community_topic], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
```

it have to send request to /shop/walmart/topic/14/update (or 'new' if @community_topic is a new record)

community.rb:

```
you can just

def to_param
  community_name
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
  resources :community_topics, :path => "topic"#, :as => :'topic' *
end

# * named route 'community_topic' can conflict with 'community_topics' of standalone route for CommunityTopic. Let it be by default: 'community_community_topic'.
```

Comment: Thanks but it stil takes me to example.com/shop/14/topic/14/edit

Comment: try to erase :as => :'topic' from route

Comment: Okay. I will give it a try

Comment: now it says undefined method `community_topics_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000001f7dd8a8>:0x0000001f3013c0>

Comment: thats right, replace all community_topic_path with 'community_community_topics_path'

Comment: It says **undefined method `community_topic_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000001f2d3150>:0x0000001f2ce290>**  because of this **<%= form_for([@community, @community_topic], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21777/discussion-between-valery-kvon-and-mkk)